# Classic ASP + Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I am looking for resources to learn classic ASP with JavaScript but I can find only those with VBScript. Could someone suggest best way to learn Classic ASP with JavaScript and some references for the same?

Thanks

Comment: Agreed, learning this is only useful for maintaing old systems or using an old copy of dreamweaver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are tutorials available with examples in both VB and JavaScript available at [W3 Schools ASP centre](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/default.asp)

Though as indicated in the comments, classic ASP is not advisable.  **Without ancient wisdom**, it is notoriously difficult to debug and has no built-in security frameworks to help you on your way.  I would stringly advise using ASP.net or PHP instead.

Good luck!!!

**EDIT**

I found a couple more:-

[Codefixer](http://www.codefixer.com/tutorials/index.asp)

[ASPtutorial/](http://www.asptutorial.info/)

Other than that you really are going to struggle without some second-hand books.  It would seem that almost the entire web has abandoned ASP with javascript.

Comment: "Classic asp is notoriously difficult to debug" No thats not correct, Classic ASP is notoriously known for its users not knowing they can debug it ;) Just allow debugging in IIS, manually (or via macro) attach visual studio debugger to w3wp (unmanaged) and enjoy ;) And it's there since Visual Studio 6, why almost noone knows about it is a mistery.

Comment: I stand by what I say ... by comparison other frameworks are far simpler and easier to debug.

Comment: I agree with @jhexp. I'm a Classic ASP and VBScript developer and I can tell if you know what you are doing you can have lots of fun with it. But, at the same token, to me, Classic ASP is an old and dated programming language and there is very limited support for it out there. If you just started learning, I would suggest picking either .NET or PHP.

Comment: @Jay It was replaced 15 years ago, I'm shocked there are still people out there who still use it

Comment: @Merlin, I agree with you. Classic ASP is a very old programing language with lots of limitations but believe it or not, still lots of developers who use it and quite frankly happy with it. I'm one of them :)

Comment: @Jay you are responding to a two years old comment on a 6 years old question, no wonders that you are still with classic asp ;)

Comment: @jhexp I have modified my answer to reflect your mystical debugging ways.  Damn I was stubborn back then.  In order to make amends and join the legions of past, I am learning perl today.

Comment: @Merlin Haha, nice. Sometimes I'm sad that this craft of manually attached debuggers will disappear when our generation dies out.

Answer (score 0):

You could also lookat the tutorial at [Tizag](http://www.tizag.com/aspTutorial/). They also have a JavaScript one and some other stuff. I used it some when I was learning some of it. I am sorry that classic ASP is your only choice.